# Quickly jump to scene in Xcode storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

Is there any way to quickly jump to a scene in a storyboard? I have about 30 different scenes/view controllers and it has become incredibly tedious to locate the view controller I'm trying to edit.

Comment: Ya in the left panel in storyboard click on the view controller name under the scene you want to go to.

Comment: Looking for something faster than this, I have 30 view controllers, scrolling through the list to find the one I'm looking for takes time. The search bar at the bottom of that left panel would be useful except it doesn't work. (it will filter the items in the panel but it won't jump you to its location on storyboard)

Comment: I have near 30 scenes too. It takes 2 seconds to scroll that list. Good named viewcontroller should be easy to fine from the list. The bottom search works to filter scenes but you still have to click the scene you want. Takes 2 seconds to click a scene after searching.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is select the view controller in the IB editor (click the little yellow circle under the view). Then select a visible title for a view controller in the side panel (just to give the side panel focus) then hit the down arrow. It'll auto-scroll the panel to highlight the currently selected view controller.

Comment: You misunderstood my question: when you're in IB, looking at a storyboard, how can you easily jump to a specific scene/view controller in the storyboard.